# Does LAV Filter do the YUV to RGB conversion

Tags: glsl, video-processing, decoder

I would like to improve decoding H.264 video stream with MPC-HC using LAV video decoder.
The stream I will play back is always in format yuvj444p (Planar YCbCr 4:4:4 in TV level [0-255]), encoded with x264.

I'm using MPC-HC version 1.7.10, and LAV video decoder 0.68.1
I have a nVidia Quadro K5200, and I know how to write GLSL shader to run YUV to RGB conversion.

I'm wondering if someone here could give me a hint if it's worth doing such job, and possibly on where to start.

- Should I customize the EVR (Enhanced Video Renderer - Custom Presenter) ?
- Should I just write an internal shader?
- ...

Comment: Do you refer RGB specifically or RGBA output format also answers your question?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether it's worth doing "such a job". Do you mean "is it worth using a shader instead of doing software yuv-rgb conversion"? (The answer is "yes".) Or something else?

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje As a first step, I was wondering who did the YUV -> RGB conversion, so I asked if LAVFilters does. It's wasn't the best best question I shall have asked. Abyways, now I've discovered that I could configure LAVFilters to output as YV24 or RGB24 in the option. But if I output as YV24, the EVR couldn't display it. So I installed madVR. But overall FPS performance is decreased... So I will ask a new question I guess.

Comment: If the topic is of interest to you, my next question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529041/h264-decoding-with-lav-filter-increase-fps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, LAV Video Decoder filter does support yuvj444p to RGB32 color conversion.

In order to prove it, I have tried the following test:

1. Create uncompressed AVI file in RGB color format (using MATLAB).
2. Convert the AVI file to x264 compressed MKV file in yuvj444p color format (using FFMPEG).
3. Build a filter graph in Graph Studio Next, with LAV Video Decoder (DirectShow) filter.
4. Inspect the output pin of Decoder filter.
5. Play the graph, and compare the output frame to original input frame.

Input AVI file name: RGB_INPUT.avi
MKV file name: OUTPUT.mkv
I used ffmpeg with the following parameters (in command line):
`ffmpeg -i RGB_INPUT.avi -pix_fmt yuvj444p -vf scale=w=0:h=0:out_color_matrix=bt709 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -x264opts colorprim=bt709:transfer=bt709:colormatrix=bt709 -an OUTPUT.mkv`
I took the example from here: http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1671195

Filter Graph:
[image]

Inspecting the output pin of LAV Video Decoder, shows that output color format is RGB32 (media sub-type is: `MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32`):
[image]

Comparing uncompressed input frame, to decoded output frame:

Source frame (uncompressed image):
[image]

Video Renderer output (screenshot):
[image]

Absolute difference image (scaled by 10):
[image]

Conclusion: **LAV Video Decoder correctly convert yuvj444 to RGB32.**

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot @Rotem. May I ask you another sub question now? Do you think it's feasible to ask LAV Video Decoder to not do the YUV -> RGB conversion, and then I will run it thanks to a shader on GPU? My point is to decrease overall render time.